# Tuple, array or vector of vectors as argument of a function

Tags: rust, variadic, rust-macros

I want to be able to provide vectors as arguments from an array of vectors to a macro iproduct!, which accepts varying numbers of arguments (all arguments must be Iterator element type).

Most important is the possibility of providing arrays with different lengths.

It seems that the method is called "Variadic function", which seems it is not yet implemented on Rust. Please, let me know your constructive comments. Thank you!

This is the idea, but it will not work as I intend.

```
// main.rs
use itertools::iproduct;

fn main() {
    let arr = [vec![1,2,3],vec![0,1,2]];
    let mut result = Vec::new();
    for tupl in iproduct!(arr) {
        result.push(tupl);
    };
    println!("{:?}", result)
}
// current output: [[1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2]]
// expected output: [[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2],[3,0],[3,1],[3,2]]
```

So far, this works well, but it is static depending on the number of arguments and only for strings. I am forced to write several different combinations and still would be covering a few cases.

```
use itertools::iproduct;

type TS2 = (String,String);
type TS3 = (String,String,String);

pub fn cartesian_2vec(l1: Vec<String>, l2: Vec<String>) -> Vec<TS2> {
    let mut collector = Vec::new();
    for tupl in iproduct!(l1,l2) {
        collector.push(tupl);
    };
    collector
}

pub fn cartesian_3vec(l1: Vec<String>, l2: Vec<String>, l3: Vec<String>) -> Vec<TS3> {
    let mut collector = Vec::new();
    for tupl in iproduct!(l1,l2,l3) {
        collector.push(tupl);
    };
    collector
}

fn main() {
    let list1 = vec![String::from('1'),String::from('2'),String::from('3')];
    let list2 = vec![String::from('a'),String::from('b')];

    println!("{:?}", cartesian_2vec(list1,list2))

}
// [("1", "a"), ("1", "b"), ("2", "a"), ("2", "b"), ("3", "a"), ("3", "b")]
```

Comment: Rust does not have variadic functions. You will either have to convert `cartesian` into a macro as well, or change it to take an iterator and use [`multi_cartesian_product`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.multi_cartesian_product) instead. (but that function is limited to when all iterators have the same item type)

Comment: Also one nit: You can just do `iproduct!(l1, l2, l3).collect()` instead of manually looping through and pushing into a vector.

Comment: *"which seems it is not yet implemented on Rust"* - I don't think it's not done **yet**, I think I've read somewhere that it was a conscious decision to not implement it at all, due to type safety reasons. Rust also has no overloaded functions for the same reason. Everything variadic (like `println`) is supposed to be solved with macros, to my understanding. Note that Rust macros are much safer and more typed than C++ macros, so don't panic about that decision :)

Comment: Thanks, @PitaJ. In my case, multi_cartesian_product would work very well, and I was unaware! I am curious about the macros option for other similar cases. Providing at once the iterators items as arguments...

Comment: Thanks, @Finomnis, for the clarification. It would b great if you could post an example that implements this with a macro or point out some online resources. I have found simple examples using println!("{}", $Args) but this is not the same case. Thanks!

Comment: @Carlos_G Maybe this helps: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/macros/variadics.html or https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/8vze9e/help_writing_a_variadic_macro/, specifically https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8038c3774e438a3d8d9ec39b641fcde1&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015. It's basically recursive destructuring

Comment: Although in your case this won't be necessary, a single repetition should suffice (as you don't handle the arguments but only forward them to another macro)

Answer (score 1):

Variadic functions don't exist in Rust. Instead, they are usually modelled with macros:

```rust
use itertools::iproduct;

macro_rules! cartesian_vecs {
    ($($l:expr),+) => {{
        let mut collector = Vec::new();
        for tupl in iproduct!($($l),+) {
            collector.push(tupl);
        }
        collector
    }};
}

fn main() {
    let list1 = vec![String::from('1'), String::from('2'), String::from('3')];
    let list2 = vec![String::from('a'), String::from('b')];

    println!("{:?}", cartesian_vecs!(list1, list2));
}
```

```
[("1", "a"), ("1", "b"), ("2", "a"), ("2", "b"), ("3", "a"), ("3", "b")]
```

Or the even shorter version:

```rust
use itertools::iproduct;

macro_rules! cartesian_vecs {
    ($($l:expr),+) => {{
        iproduct!($($l),+).collect::<Vec<_>>()
    }};
}

fn main() {
    let list1 = vec![String::from('1'), String::from('2'), String::from('3')];
    let list2 = vec![String::from('a'), String::from('b')];

    println!("{:?}", cartesian_vecs!(list1, list2));
}
```

```
[("1", "a"), ("1", "b"), ("2", "a"), ("2", "b"), ("3", "a"), ("3", "b")]
```

Comment: Hi @Finomnis, Thank you for providing an example. It looks great; It almost answers my question. Would it be possible to edit it? Instead of several arguments as input, it only accepts one input, a tuple, array or vector, whichever is more straightforward, for instance, `cartesian_vecs!(vec![list1, list2])` assuming that can also apply for another iterator length. Thanks!

Comment: @Carlos_G something like this? https://gist.github.com/kylewlacy/115965b40e02a3325558#file-cartesian_product-rs

Comment: Yes! line 45 `cartesian_product<T: Clone>(lists: &[&[T]]) -> Vec<Vec<T>>`. Great, so now I can try to generalize it for other functions. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Carlos_G you probably shouldn't have tagged your question `variadic`, then you would have actually gotten answers like this :) this isn't variadic.